# Is there a Circular data structure for Java? ie CircularLinkedList

Tags: java

I am looking for a circular data structure to use in Java. I remember in my data structures class that there was a data structure called a CircularLinkedList.

High level:

My use case is that I need to iterate over the list until its empty. For example, consider a deck of cards. I would like to remove all 10's then all 5's then all Jacks in any order of my choosing. That is just a high level example.

Detailed:

I need to process objects that have dependencies. I cannot process an object with a field of 'B' before one of field 'A'. There is no inherent sort and I would like to get this to work and then improve later if it is even needed. I would like to process these objects out of order. If the object has a dependency that has not been processed, I would like to skip over it and loop the list until it's empty.

However, I cannot find the data structure in java. Google searches result in implementations by others, again for programming courses. Before I accept that there is no implementation for this in the Java collections, I wanted to post a question here to be certain. Afterall it could just have a name for it that I did not remember.

Comment: I know nothing like that in the JDK, but honestly the only way to find out is to look at the Collections doc

Comment: @yshavit I am open to another technique to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Dici I have looked through the documentation and have not found anything so far. Mainly I wanted to make sure I was not searching for the wrong terms.

Comment: @yshavit don't think it's circular in the sense the OP means it. To me, an iterator on a circular data-structure will never be exhausted unless the underlying DS is mutated during the iteration or empty from the start. This is not the behaviour of `ArrayDeque`

Comment: @Mark what is the cardinality of the type of the nodes ? Your algorithm seems very expensive for high cardinalities

Comment: @Dici I agree it can be very expensive. Right now it's not bad enough that I need to worry about it. However, in the future it might be. Right now I just need it to work. If I had to put a value to it, I would say total objects would be 1000 and maybe 15% have dependencies. Sorry for not answering sooner. I just saw the comment. There was 5+ comments at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your requirement seems to be this sentence:

> If the object has a dependency that has not been processed, I would like to skip over it and loop the list until it's empty.

That's easy enough. You use a [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), where you take the first value from the queue using [`poll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll()). If you cannot use the value yet, you add it back to the end of the queue using [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#add(E)). You keep taking the head value until the `Queue` is empty, e.g. when `poll()` returns `null`.

For your purpose, an [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) is likely your best option for `Queue` implementation<strike>, or a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) if you prefer</strike>.

Comment: I did consider this but I thought it would not be efficient because I would be constantly manipulating the structure which is not needed. I just need to loop back.

Comment: @Mark With `LinkedList` you're right; each remove and re-add causes memory allocations. Not so for `ArrayDeque`, which internally is a circular array-buffer, so adding and removing is fast and allocation-less. As the javadoc says: *[`ArrayDeque`] is likely to be faster than `Stack` when used as a stack, and faster than `LinkedList` when used as a queue.*

Comment: @Andreas I believe your last statements are wrong. Removal at the middle of an `ArrayDeque` results in a shift of the elements while it's a simple pointer switch in a `LinkedList`. If you look at the implementation of `ArrayDeque.iterator`, the `remove` method calls `ArrayDeque.delete`, which is private and contains calls to `Systen.arraycopy`

Comment: +1 Interesting...I did not know that. If that is the case then I think this will be the easiest option. Thanks!

Comment: @Dici If you use `ArrayDeque` as a **queue**, you'll only ever remove the head, and never from the "middle". If you read my answer again, you'll notice that I did *not* suggest to actually *iterate* the queue, but rather continuously pull the head and send "skipped" items to the tail.

Comment: @Mark but again, the implementation of `addLast` clearly isn't allocation-less since it may have to double the capacity of the internal array. Although I agree that the overall, amortized performance is better (the javadoc says so, I believe them), I think your statements are a bit too broad

Comment: @Dici After the initial fill of the queue, the actual continuous looping until empty will no longer cause array-increase. If you have lots of objects initially, you can pre-size the array, same as you can for `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Andreas true, you bought me

Answer (score 1):

Guava has an [Iterables.cycle](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#cycle(java.lang.Iterable)) method which does exactly this.  The docs even suggest this type of use case.  Perhaps that's what you want?

Comment: Guava's really nice, +1. However, I can't think of any edge case which makes the implementation of such a method very difficult, so I would avoid abusive dependencies if possible